# How to provide checkall option to select and deselect all checkboxes in Gridmvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Add(m => m.TagId)
.Titled("")
.Sanitized(false)
.Encoded(false)
.RenderValueAs(d => Html.CheckBox("Checked", false));
columns.Add(alarm => alarm.DomainName).Titled("Domain");
columns.Add(alarm => alarm.GroupName).Titled("Groups").Sortable(true);
}).Sortable(true)
```

above is my Gridmvc in MVC,here i want to provide checkall option in the header of the grid and also id to that checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Its not jquery variable its **javascript array**
 for you. Need to use js `push()` function to create that array. like this

```
var mydata = new Array();
for (var i = 0, il = ids.length; i < il; i++) {
 mydata.push(ids[i]);
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: suppose mydata=sathya then i want add mydata="domain/"+mydata, to all values of mydata for each loop

Comment: can any one provide to set for selectall option using @gridmvc.html